# Delete Image Files From Server

Tags: php, delete-file

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/deletetest.php#/0) page which allows users to view their uploaded images in a gallery format.

I'm now wanting to add the delete functionality to each image. I've created the button and the Javascript behind it, but I'm really not sure how to link the 'button click' with the actual physical deletion of the file.

The images aren't stored in a database but are in two folder locations on my server, in the following structure:

`UploadedFiles/username/locationid/imagename` and

`UploadedFiles/username/locationid/Thumbnails/imagename`

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm now reaching the limits of my knowledge, but certainly willing to learn. From the documentation I've read I think I'm correct in saying that the `unlink` method is the correct command to use?

But what I'm finding really difficult is telling the code to find the folders with the `username` and `locationid` folders which match the current `username` and `locationid` and then delete the files which match the `$source` name variable.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps provide some guidance please on how I may go about this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can pass the username, locationid, and imagename variables to your script, you can delete the files using `unlink()`:

```
$path = 'UploadedFiles/' . $username . '/' . $locationid . '/';

unlink( $path . $imagename );
unlink( $path . 'Thumbnails/' . $imagename );
```

Because you are interacting with your file system, you'll want to be sure and sanitize the variables (prevent someone from using ../../../ to get to unwanted parts of your file system).

```
$username = str_replace( array( '..', '/', '\\', ':' ), '', $username );
$imagename = str_replace( array( '..', '/', '\\', ':' ), '', $imagename );
$locationid= str_replace( array( '..', '/', '\\', ':' ), '', $locationid );
```

Comment: you may also want to make sure you escape .. characters in the filename otherwise you could something like "../../../public/index.php"

Comment: I don't know if it goes without mentioning, so I will mention: your code should be structured so the variable sanitization lines run before the $path= and unlink() lines.

Comment: Hi @PaulBain and @Set Sail Media. Thank you very much for your help with this. I've added the code, where I think it should go, within the button click action? but when I add the piece of code starting with `spath`, my image software is affected and I lose the `Thumbnail` functionality. I was also wondering, and forgive me for asking a beginners question, is it possible to use the `$imagename` when I don't declare it until later on in my script, to be precise row 124 which starts `<a href="<?php echo $source; ?>">` I've updated my link to reflect the changes I've made. Kind regards

Comment: I see what you've done, and unfortunately that will not work, you can't simply include the code in your main index file. It will run as the rest of the output is processed, which is not your desired effect. To achieve the behavior you're after, you'll need to use the code in a PHP file all by itself, and then call that PHP file using AJAX (or some other request) and include the variables in your request.

Comment: We will want the PHP to run only when the button is clicked, and we'll need to do this by either sending the visitor to another page (delete.php?username=XX&imagename=YY&locationid=ZZ) or process the request in the background (AJAX) using JavaScript (I prefer the jQuery library). See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Hi both, this is great. It really gives me a good start. Many thanks for all your time and trouble. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your javascript (client-side) will have to call a URL (server-side) to delete the picture that the user selected. I propose that for now you do it statically (if later you wanna move to something more dynamic, the step to transform into ajax in rather small.

So as Set Sail Media said, you will have to pass the username and locationID to your server when clicking on the delete button. One way to do that is:

When rendering your gallery in HTML/javascript, for each picture, you had below it a  which will contain the needed information and the submit button will simply call the delete script from your server. An example of form that you could do is:

```
    <form name="deleteImageX" method="GET" target="your.server.org/deleteImage.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" value="theUserNameAssociatedWithThePicture" />
        <input type="hidden" name="locationId" value="locationOfThePicture" />
        <input type="submit" value="delete"/>
    </form>
```

This form will store the needed value in hidden fields which will not be displayed on the webpage but will still be sent to the server when pressing the submit button.

(for the little story, the method used here is GET because AFAIK HTML doesn't support the DELETE method (which would have been suitable in our case)).

The GET method will call the script "your.server.org/deleteImage.php". In this script you will have all the information you need (username/locationId) to delete the image by using the $_GET['username'] and $_GET['locationId'] variables. Then as you mentioned, you will need to use the unlink method to actually delete the file from the server.

Finally once this is done you need to redirect the php script so that after deleting the image you display the gallery again (for instance). This can be done by calling a script if you have some sort of template engine, or by calling the "header" function of php.

Comment: Hi @bear foot, thank you very much for taking the time to explain all of this, it is greatly appreciated. As I said in my original post, I'me really very new to this, so it just may take me sometime to digest the technical details you've kindly provided. So I may have some questions a little later on. Kind regards

Comment: No problem. Take your time, enjoy PHP and of course there is no such thing as stupid question. If you can't find a straight answer on php.net (which is a pretty good php bible) or on Google, feel free to ask. BR, Bear

Comment: Many thanks @bear foot, it's funny I was just looking at php.net. Kind regards