# jQuery POST To Delete File On Button Click

Tags: php, jquery, delete-file

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/deletetest.php) page which allows users to view a gallery of their uploaded images.

I'm now working on the `deletion` functionality, so that users can delete any image. From some really useful guidance from members of this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499450/delete-image-files-from-server), I've been looking at the jQuery POST method, `unlinking` the images from the server where they're stored.

From their guidance and subsequent research I've been doing, I think I can use the relative path  i.e. `$path`.

I've come up with the following which I've tried to add to my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    Galleria.ready(function() {
        this.$('thumblink').click();

        $(".galleria-image").append( 
            "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
            $(".btn-delete").live("click", function() 
            { var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 
                alert('Deleting image... ');
                $(this).closest(".galleria-image"). fadeOut('slow');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "$path",
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Unfortunately though, I've clearly done soemthing wrong because this has affected my gallery functionality and it no longer works. Perhaps, because I'm quite new to this, I've looked at it too simplistically, I'm not sure.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: You need to use PHP to delete the file. There's an `unlink` function included in PHP for this. If you have written any PHP code related to this, post it here. If not, you need to start write some.

Comment: For the start, url in ajax code isn't valid. You are using a php variable in  jquery. It won't work. Put it inside php tags and echo it.

Comment: Both, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and for setting me right on this. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brackets don't match after the

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "$path",
}
```

which is probably why the javascript is broken.

Comment: Hi @thelastshadow, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and for the guidance. Kind regards