# Removing an image from server

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to delete the images from the server using unlink() function. This is deleting the image name from the database, but the image is not deleted from the server, what am i doing wrong?

```
public function actionDelete()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
        {

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $product=Product::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one()->delete();
            $delete=CategoryProduct::find()->where(['product_id'=>$id])->all();
            foreach($delete as $del)
            {
                $del->delete(); 
            }

            $imgfile="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/web/assets/uploads/<?php echo $product->image;?>";
            unlink($imgfile);

            echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
        }

        echo json_encode(FALSE);die;

    }
```

Comment: Use the Filepath not the URL, i'm looking at `$app->request->baseUrl` it will return http://path/path/path/img.html but you must use the file path which is like etc/ww/images/path/direcory/file.png

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499450/delete-image-files-from-server i think it may help you

Comment: use `Yii::getAlias('webroot')` for file path

Comment: Use getcwd() to get the current working directory.

Comment: `$imgfile="<?php echo `... you are already in a PHP-block. It should be: `$imgfile= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl  .  '/web/assets/uploads/' . $product->image;` . But as others have pointed out... this will give you the URL, not the actual file path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Its is best to set an alias for the upload path (best place will be `config/bootstrap.php`)so that we can have standard name to all the upload folder. i.e

```
Yii::setAlias('image_uploads', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/web/assets/uploads');
```

You can use the same for saving and deleting the file.

Saving will be like

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, \Yii::getAlias('@image_uploads/products/') . $product->image);
```

or

You can use Yii Methods i.e for e.g.

```
$this->imageFile->saveAs($orignal_file_full_path); // where imageFile in input type file
```

Deleting will be something like:

```
unlink (\Yii::getAlias('@image_uploads/products/') . $product->image);
```

the Core idea is to use real paths for deleting and saving rather then URLs