# Erasing multiple images from folder

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with erasing some pictures.I have been making function for adding multiple images. It is all working smoothly, except for a small problem, and that is that I'm unable to delete those images from the folder. It all gets erased in the database, as it should, but the images remain in the folder. Here is what that part of the code for erasing looks like. If you can, please help.

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET['delete_image'] ) ) {
  $imgi = (int) $_GET['imgi'] - 1;
  $images = explode( ',', $kola['images'] );
  $image_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $images[$imgi];
  unlink( $image_url );
  unset( $images[$imgi] );
  $imageString = implode( ',', $images );
  $dbc->query("UPDATE `cars` SET `images` = '{$imageString}' WHERE `id` = '{$edit_id}'");
  header('Location: edit_information.php?edit=' . $edit_id );
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Image Files From Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499450/delete-image-files-from-server)

Comment: What is your error log showing? If $image_url has the right path, unlink() should work.

Comment: Where those images placed by php? Or by some other user on the server?

Comment: If you have multiple images dont you need a loop somewhere?

Comment: Does a little change: `$image_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$images[$imgi];` to: `$image_url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $images[$imgi];` help?

Comment: You could also debug by: `echo (is_file($image_url) ? 'Yes!!!':'Huh? No.');`

Comment: You cant take a list of images, put it on the end of your document_root, and then unlink it.  You'll need to either write a function to do the delete (unlink), or make a loop in-line to delete them.   Plus, are they sitting in document_root, or did you stick them in a folder?  If in a folder, you should add the folder to your filename.  IF you are not dropping them into a folder, you should consider doing so.

Comment: the suggestive edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17807560 is attempting to modify / add characters to the code; I rejected it.

Comment: ps, unlink returns bool success, so `if(!unlink($image_url)){throw new \RuntimeException('failed to delete image! '.$image_url);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I'm really amazed by the amount of support and help I have gotten from you people here. The problem was in the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].  Because, during the addition of the picture into the base, I used a full path, $dbpath .= 'images/kolaalex/'.$uploadName;  and that is why it got written twice. It was enough to throw out $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  and the problem disappeared.  I thank you all again, and especially thanks to var_dump :)